# JSP Servlet save as popup

Tags: jsp, servlets, popup, save

I want to download data in the excel to user selected path and in jsp i have given ExportToExcel button,so i want below scenario

When user click on ExportToExcel Button then save as popup window should come and from there i want to call servlet and need to receive file save path in servlet  which was selected from popup window and then finally i want to write my data to the excel sheet and save to the user selected path. Once it saved then i want to show one message to the user in another jsp page.

Answer (score 2):

The information about the file save path is not sent to the server in any way. Plus, you would obviously not be able to use e.g. `new File(savedPath)` in the server when the client runs at a physically different machine as would occur in non-development environments. So your whole requirement just doesn't make any sense. You should just write the file directly to the HTTP response body of the very same HTTP response which triggers the *Save As* dialogue.

It's not clear what you're using to generate the Excel file, but if it's for example [Apache POI](http://poi.apache.org/), then it look like this:

```
HSSFWorkbook workbook = new HSSFWorkbook();
HSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet();
HSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(0);
HSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0);
cell.setCellValue("cell value");

response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel"); // Tell browser what content type the response body represents,  so that it can associate it with MS Excel, if necessary.
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=name.xls"); // Force "Save As" dialogue.
workbook.write(response.getOutputStream()); // Write created Excel sheet to response. This will be saved in the location specified by the user.
```